# Jawbone API - faulty node - Service Unavailable

Tags: jawbone

It seems like the Jawbone API has a problem on one of its nodes. When calling the endpoints below sometimes requests succeed and sometimes fail with an "Service Unavailable" response. The requests are the same an I have tried the calls from different machines.
Any one else experiencing the same problem?

Endpoints: 
https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/moves
https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/workouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be resolved now.

tl;dr: Some changes in routing resulted in malformed requests to the servers. The servers stopped responding, so nginx gave you a 503.

Original Answer:

> The Jawbone partner API servers are suffering a minor outage. The team
>   is looking into the issue. As you noted, it's not a complete downtime.
>
> There is no ETA for resolution yet. I'll update this answer when I know more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I hope it can be resolved soon because it looks like more calls are failing than succeeding.

Comment: Looks like the team has found the failing spot in the code. Fix should get deployed soon.